# Use pex with poetry pyproject.toml

Tags: deployment, python-poetry, python-pex

I'm trying to figure out how to do automated(ish) deployment for a python project with pex. I currently have the following process:

```
$ poetry run pip freeze > requirements.txt 
manually remove this-project line from requirements.txt
$ poetry run pex -r requirements.txt -o service.pex -e api:start --sources-directory=.
$ ./service.pex
```

The reason for the second step is that pex will try to find `this-project` online if I leave the line in. This I understand, but `pip freeze` does insert that line in `requirements.txt`. What I'm wondering is: can pex use `pyproject.toml` or `poetry.lock` directly? The current solution is kind of an annoying work around.

I've looked at [2019 tutorial](https://steve.dignam.xyz/2019/11/17/pex-and-poetry/) and it doesn't work, since the current version of pex doesn't recognize `--project` as an option.

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

How about `pex . -o service.pex -e api:start`? Pex understands how to build any PEP-517 / PEP-518 pyproject.toml, which you've got if you're using Poetry.